# Android - access microphone from web browser

Tags: android

Is the a way to access a microphone from web browser?

I want to create a web site where i want to record a user.

Workarounds and suggestions will be very appreciated! :)

Comment: already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27846392/access-microphone-from-a-browser-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML5 tag x-webkit-speech to get this access

```
<input type="text" x-webkit-speech />
```

http://slides.html5rocks.com/#speech-input

Answer (score 0):

```
<device>
```

tag will give you access to webcam and micrphone. But unfortunately it is not yet implemented in any browser including Chrome.