# Mic Input in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, audio-recording

Brothers i'm working on a Chat application on Laravel platform, In which i want to record Voice message through browser. I searched for 3rd part library but i failed.
Or Is there any way to get audio input from mic, please do let me know.
thanks

Comment: The solution to this would probably be client-side, so not sure if php/laravel tags are appropriate. That being said, this may be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27846392/access-microphone-from-a-browser-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

I've had a run with https://github.com/feross/simple-peer but I've not gotten to integrating it with laravel.

It's [documentation](https://github.com/feross/simple-peer#videovoice) on setting up video/voice was pretty clear to me as a start, but getting beyond that I'm not sure, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ieBtXwHvoNk) is what helped me through it.

```
var SimplePeer = require('simple-peer')

// get video/voice stream
navigator.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }, gotMedia, function () {})

function gotMedia (stream) {
  var peer1 = new SimplePeer({ initiator: true, stream: stream })
  var peer2 = new SimplePeer()

  peer1.on('signal', function (data) {
    peer2.signal(data)
  })

  peer2.on('signal', function (data) {
    peer1.signal(data)
  })

  peer2.on('stream', function (stream) {
    // got remote video stream, now let's show it in a video tag
    var video = document.querySelector('video')
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream)
    video.play()
  })
}
```