# How to get PCM from microphone in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, audio, frontend

I'm building the WebApp using Angular with TypeScript and I need to get array of samples every 0.2 seconds with specific sample rate.

I'm new to the frontend, and I do not know how to use AudioContext or MediaRecorder correctly. I've tried some examples from net but it doesn't seem to work. It would be nice to get a working example of code.

Comment: see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27846392/access-microphone-from-a-browser-javascript/27852403#27852403

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access microphone from a browser - Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27846392/access-microphone-from-a-browser-javascript)

Comment: @ScottStensland, I tried this before, but ScriptProccessorNode is now deprecated. And I am not able to use that in typescript.