# VUE JS - Is there a built-in function to check microphone present on an android device?

Tags: android, vue.js

I am running a Vue Js application on an android device. I am trying to achieve a feature to record audio only when mic is present.

I want to know if there is some built-in function in Vue js to check if microphone is present on the device.

Comment: a microphone is present on every device, right? Otherwise, how will anyone make a call?

Comment: I am using a customized android device in which when I connect an external mic only then I can use it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe their is no build in check, but this Thread should help you: [Access microphone from a browser - Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27846392/access-microphone-from-a-browser-javascript)

Comment: Does this mean you think this is a duplicate Question?