# Capture real-time audio from mic in web application with Google Speech to Text API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have a C# MVC web application with voice input forms. I mean the user can input the values in textbox using voice via microphone. I decided to use [Google Speech to text](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text) API to achieve this. But I have some doubts to achieve this using Google Speech to Text API.

Because I am trying to implement this in an MVC Web application, so the mic device not accessible from the server-side code. I want to convert the speech from real-time audio and show the output text to the webpage.

Comment: you could use SignalR to send the input to your server call the Google API and push the result back to the client.

Comment: @Darem Thank you very much for your response. Could you please suggest any sample code.

Comment: This is from the official Microsoft page. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio. It is a simple chat app. But you can replace the string input with your microphone (byte) input and send it to your backend. I hope this helps you?

Comment: Hello @Darem, could you please post your comment as an answer so that it's more visible for other people?

Comment: @Alejandro I added my comment as a anwser.

Answer (score 3):

One solution to solve this problem would be to use [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).

You can follow this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27852403/8458043) to get the microphone input and also a very nice explanation of how to handle microphone input with websockets.

**The following is only sudo code to explain the concept!**

It is also greatly simplified, because I don't know, for example, whether Google's API can handle the fact that you always send it only fragments of speech input, etc. And as I said the code gives only a rough overview of the basic process and has no logic if the server is offline etc.

But inside of the `function process_microphone_buffer(event)`function you can call SignalR.

So the function would something like

```
function process_microphone_buffer(event) {
    // you should handle this as a singelton
    const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/speechToTextHub ").build();
    const microphone_output_buffer = event.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    connection.invoke("SendMicrophoneBuffer", microphone_output_buffer).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
}
```

And on your Server you implement a corresponding hub:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SignalRChat.Hubs
{

    public class SpeechToTextHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMicrophoneBuffer(byte[] buffer)
        {
            var googleApi = new GoogleApi();
            var speechToTextResult = await googleApi.GetTextFromSpeechAsync(buffer);
            Context.Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).SendAsync("SpeechToTextResult", speechToTextResult);
        }
    }
}
```

And on your client you have something like this

```
connection.on("SpeechToTextResult", function (textResult) {
   console.log(textResult);
});
```

If the answer is too general for Stackoverflow, I can also remove it.
If there are still open questions, I can extend my answer accordingly.