# Unable to record audio on a public webserver?

Tags: javascript, html, microphone, voice

I am building a simple voice recognition website and it works great on the local server but when running it on a webserver I get an error saying that the website is not allowed to use the microphone.

I've looked for a while about how to fix this but it seems that all anyone can tell me is to just run it on a local server. however, I don't want to run it on a local server I want to be able to access it from multiple computers.

Is there any way of getting around this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access microphone from a browser - Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27846392/access-microphone-from-a-browser-javascript)

Comment: No when i do this i get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getUserMedia' of undefined

Answer (score -1):

You could try adding the following snippet to see what error is being generated.

```
recognition.onerror = function(event) {
    console.log(event.error);
};
```

Comment: What is `recognition` supposed to be?